# How to use Apache Tika on Android

Tags: android, apache-tika

I'm trying to use Apache tika to parse some documents but it giving me so many errors and warnings.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile ('org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.14'){
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'}
...
}
```

To make this question easier to read, I'll not paste the warnings here (they are 600+) and I will ignore them but the errors are these:

```
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/ReferenceResolver;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLEvent;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLInputStream;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLName;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLStreamException;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/utils/NestedThrowable;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/utils/NestedThrowable$Util;
Error:8 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Please do you have a solution to this. Or better still, do you know a better library that I can use to extract the metadata of documents?

Comment: Did you find solution? If yes, please post it in answers.

Comment: @AnujaKothekar No I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use this one, its working for me.

```
compile group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers', version: '1.14'
```

Answer (score 0):

**FOR ANYONE WHO CAME ACROSS THIS**

The solution is **deprecated** in newer versions

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

In **Depedencies** put this.

```
classpath 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.14'
```